# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xAxis' of undefined Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

i try to make synchronize zoom from more than 2 charts, just like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/

The problem is the chart is showing but in console there is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xAxis' of undefined" and the synchronize not work either.

This is my code.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            var chart1;
            var chart2;


        $.getJSON('http://sine.co.id/PHESIAK/laporan/getJSON.php', function (data) {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
                chart1 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                    },      


                title: {
                    text: 'Data Monitoring Uji Coba Fast',
                    style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: '50px'
                }
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Temperature Sensor Well Head 81',
                    style: {
                    color: '#3366AA',
                    fontSize: '30px'
                    }
                },

                xAxis: {
                    gapGridLineWidth: 0,
                    events: {
                            afterSetExtremes: function (event) {
                                var xMin = event.min;
                                var xMax = event.max;
                                var ex = chart2.xAxis[0].getExtremes();


                                if (ex.min != xMin || ex.max != xMax) chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);
                            }
                        }
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    }, {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1D'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        count: 1,
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                    selected: 1,
                    inputEnabled: false
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Fahrenheit',
                    type: 'area',
                    data: data,
                    gapSize: 5,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#003399'],
                            [1, '#3366AA']
                        ]
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }]
            });
        });
        });
        });
                </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        $.getJSON('http://sine.co.id/PHESIAK/laporan/getJsonPres.php', function (data1) {


        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
                chart2 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container1',
                    },  


                title: {
                    text:  ''
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Pressure Sensor Well Head 81',
                    style: {
                    color: '#D43346',
                    fontSize: '30px'
                    }
                },

                xAxis: {
                    gapGridLineWidth: 0,

                    events: {
                            afterSetExtremes: function (event) {
                                var xMin = event.min;
                                var xMax = event.max;
                                var ex = chart1.xAxis[0].getExtremes();


                                if (ex.min != xMin || ex.max != xMax) chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);
                            }
                        }
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    }, {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1D'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        count: 1,
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                    selected: 1,
                    inputEnabled: false
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'PSI',
                    type: 'area',
                    data: data1,
                    gapSize: 5,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#ad1a2c'],
                            [1, '#D43346']
                        ]
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }]
            });
        });
        });
                </script>
```

any advice guys ? i think i'm stuck. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It seems you copy pasted the code for the second chart and didn't rename chart1 to chart2, you're acessing chart1.xAxis where chart1 is undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have your 2 charts set up inside an ajax call (`$.getJSON`). Therefor the 2 charts do not know about each other. Option would be to wrap both of your charts in a single ajax method (or nested ajax method). This may have its own pitfalls but then the charts would at least "know" about each other.

Yet another option is to define your charts outside the ajax methods and just update the charts with the data upon successful data call.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript did not know your chart1 and chart2 variabels global cause its hold in a function,
you have some options:

```
1: 
var chart1 = $('#container').highcharts();
var chart2 = $('#container1').highcharts();
```

or use

```
2:
$('#container').highcharts().xAxis[0].setExtremes
$('#container1').highcharts().xAxis[0].setExtremes
```

btw you using highstock not highcharts
just edited by hand in notepad, try maybe work ^^

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var chart1;
var chart2;

$.getJSON('http://sine.co.id/PHESIAK/laporan/getJSON.php?callback=?',  function(data) {

 chart1 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
   chart: {
     renderTo: 'container1',
   },


   title: {
     text: 'Data Monitoring Uji Coba Fast',
     style: {
       color: 'black',
       fontWeight: 'bold',
       fontSize: '50px'
     }
   },

   subtitle: {
     text: 'Temperature Sensor Well Head 81',
     style: {
       color: '#3366AA',
       fontSize: '30px'
     }
   },

   xAxis: {
     gapGridLineWidth: 0,
     events: {
       afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
         var xMin = event.min;
         var xMax = event.max;
         var ex = chart2.xAxis[0].getExtremes();


         if (ex.min != xMin || ex.max != xMax) chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);
       }
     }
   },

   rangeSelector: {
     buttons: [{
       type: 'hour',
       count: 1,
       text: '1h'
     }, {
       type: 'day',
       count: 1,
       text: '1D'
     }, {
       type: 'all',
       count: 1,
       text: 'All'
     }],
     selected: 1,
     inputEnabled: false
   },

   series: [{
     name: 'Fahrenheit',
     type: 'area',
     data: data,
     gapSize: 5,
     tooltip: {
       valueDecimals: 2
     },
     fillColor: {
       linearGradient: {
         x1: 0,
         y1: 0,
         x2: 0,
         y2: 1
       },
       stops: [
         [0, '#003399'],
         [1, '#3366AA']
       ]
     },
     threshold: null
   }]
 });
 });






$.getJSON('http://sine.co.id/PHESIAK/laporan/getJsonPres.php?callback=?', function(data1) {
 chart2 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
   chart: {
     renderTo: 'container2',
   },


   title: {
     text: ''
   },

   subtitle: {
     text: 'Pressure Sensor Well Head 81',
     style: {
       color: '#D43346',
       fontSize: '30px'
     }
   },

   xAxis: {
     gapGridLineWidth: 0,

     events: {
       afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
         var xMin = event.min;
         var xMax = event.max;
         var ex = chart1.xAxis[0].getExtremes();


         if (ex.min != xMin || ex.max != xMax) chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);
       }
     }
   },

   rangeSelector: {
     buttons: [{
       type: 'hour',
       count: 1,
       text: '1h'
     }, {
       type: 'day',
       count: 1,
       text: '1D'
     }, {
       type: 'all',
       count: 1,
       text: 'All'
     }],
     selected: 1,
     inputEnabled: false
   },

   series: [{
     name: 'PSI',
     type: 'area',
     data: data1,
     gapSize: 5,
     tooltip: {
       valueDecimals: 2
     },
     fillColor: {
       linearGradient: {
         x1: 0,
         y1: 0,
         x2: 0,
         y2: 1
       },
       stops: [
         [0, '#ad1a2c'],
         [1, '#D43346']
       ]
     },
     threshold: null
   }]
 });
});
});
```